# Tables cell fixed width / overflow query from a CSS noobie

Tags: css

I am trying to create a table of width 50vw that has fixed column widths of 100px. I would also like to have a vertical scroll as the widths of the columns exceed that of the table. I can either get the table to scroll (by adding display: block to .Table), but the cells width are no longer 100px; or I can get the cell widths to 100px, but the table no longer scrolls and extends way passed half of the screen. I have tried styling tbody and rows etc, but with no luck. Any help would be really appreciated.

This CSS produces the non-scrolling table:

```
.Table{
    width:50vw;
    height:30%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    overflow: scroll;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.Cell{
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

My Code is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './app.module.css';
const results = (props) => {

  let i = 0;
  let player1Numbers = props.points.map(x => { return <td className={classes.Cell}>{[x][0][0]}</td> });
  let player2Numbers = props.points.map(x => { return <td className={classes.Cell}>{[x][0][1]}</td> });
  let headers = props.points.map(x => { i++; return <th className={classes.Cell}>Game {i}</th> });


  console.log(player1Data);

  return (<React.Fragment>
    <table className={classes.Table}>

      <tr className={classes.Row}>
        <th className={classes.Cell}>Player</th>
        {headers}

      </tr>
      <tbody className={classes.tbody}>
        <tr className={classes.Row}>
          <td className={classes.Cell}> Player</td>
          {player1Numbers}
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td className={classes.Cell}>Nadal</td>
          {player2Numbers}
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div className={classes.Space}></div>
  </React.Fragment>);
}

export default results
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To add horizontal scroll to a table of "fixed width" you need a wrapping container. See example below where I've added a surrounding div.

```css
div {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 350px; /* or 50vw */
  border: 1px solid green;
}

table {
    width:100%;
    height:30%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    table-layout: fixed;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

td {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```